# Using a Storyboard for many apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, modularity

I have two apps where have some same settings. Meaning that in every app there is a share button and a rate button, with the same functionality.

What I do is to copy paste the code in order to create the same functionality (for the rate and share buttons). In fact they have similar design and both are in the same View controller.

So, I want to develop a project where those two buttons (with same design and functionality) will be placed and when I develop a new app to call it, instead of copying and pasting the code.

In a search that I did I find that Storyboard Reference can be a solution(without being sure). Also I have seen about iOS Frameworks.

Please I would like to have your opinions.

Thanks

Comment: What about creating a new target in the same project?

Comment: I have used different targets for different databases till now, I cannot imagine how this could help, could you please explain it more ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pack the code that you want to reuse as a static library(plus resource bundle) or framework or cocoapods project, then you can reuse it for multiple projects without have to copy paste source code

Comment: You mean to create the view controller which contains the common functionality in a lib and call it in any app ?

Comment: With your requirement, if it was me, i will only create the lib that have the share and rate function, since view might be design differently, if it look totally the same then you can do that also

Comment: Thats the case, same functionality and totally same look. I think thats the answer

Comment: cocoapods or dynamic framework is both easy to implement, then can just call your storyboard programmatically from there

Comment: Is there a conflict if I develop the lib with swift and some apps are with obj c ?

Comment: Wont be any problem, im also creating obj-c lib in swift demo

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 or more apps where share some settings, then **Creating A New Target** will work for you.

Go to Project > Targets > Select the original target “MyApp Target” > Right click > Duplicate.

When duplicating a target, the default generates “ MyApp Target copy” .app, .plist, etc. We want to change that.

Rename the new target (select and press enter to edit) to “ MySecondApp Target”.

Under Build Settings, search for “ MyApp Target copy”. You need to rename Product Name to “ MySecondApp”, and rename Info.plist to “MySecondApp Target-info.plist”.

For more details: [Create-multiple-targets](http://samwize.com/2014/05/22/create-multiple-targets-slash-apps-for-1-xcode-project/)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, if you're using git, is to make it git submodule and then pull it to all your projects; comparing to option with static library it won't force you to recompile your code after every change